# How can one stop async gatt.connect() if freeze

Tags: google-chrome, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

Because of some reason some times when connecting to BLE Device via web bluetooth connect freezes.

For example when triggering 'await gatt.connect()' if it freezes for ever i wish to cancel this process and provide user possibility to start connecting process again. 
Any suggestions?

In my case this could happen if device is not responding and since it is not option to refresh page i need some elegant way to cancel this connect request. Or maybe i am thinking a wrong way and there is other approaches dealing with connecting device stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an open issue specific to Chromium/Chrome. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=684073. I wonder why no one takes care of it since it's quite an important thing in my opinion.

Comment: If anyone got any kind of workaround please share, Emil thx for answer.